# SSAS tabular model Value.NativeQuery Faield

Tags: google-bigquery, odbc, ssas, tabular

I'm trying to use Value.NativeQuery with ODBC coomection to Big Query And get Error

Original Code:

```
let
    Source = #"Odbc/dsn=Google BigQuery",
    #"prod_Database" = Source{[Name="prod",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    default_Schema = #"prod_Database"{[Name="default",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    DW_DIM_Table = default_Schema{[Name="DW_DIM",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    DW_DIM_Table
```

New Code

```
let
    Source = #"Odbc/dsn=Google BigQuery",
    MyQuery = Value.NativeQuery(#"Odbc/dsn=Google BigQuery", "SELECT * FROM `default`.DW_DIM")
in
    MyQuery
```

Error:

> The query statement is not valid.

When I'm trying Put the statement to Power Query Editor:

```
= Value.NativeQuery(#"Odbc/dsn=Google BigQuery", "SELECT * FROM `default`.DW_DIM")
```

get Error

> Expression.Error: Native queries aren't supported by this value.
>   Details:
>       Table

Comment: What happened if you changed  \`default\`.DW_DIM to  \`default.DW_DIM\`?

Comment: The same error.

Comment: Can you provide more details on your ODBC connection and the settings? If you can provide some images with full details it will help

Comment: image with odbc settings:
https://pasteboard.co/I73rG5n.png

Comment: Try upgrading to latest version 2.1.23.1031see [why](https://storage.googleapis.com/simba-bq-release/odbc/release-notes.txt) hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Now the error from code 
`let
    Source = #"Odbc/dsn=Google BigQuery",
    MyQuery = Value.NativeQuery(#"Odbc/dsn=Google BigQuery", "SELECT * FROM `default`.DW_DIM")
in
    MyQuery `
Changed to "The credentials for this operation could not be validated."

Comment: In the ODBC image you send there is a sign in button, Can you please click on it and verify you are connected

Comment: Checked,fixed, the situation as in original question

Comment: My only suggestion is to contact simba support. Maybe other will have others ideas on this

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with Athena ODBC (which is also a Simba Driver) but was able to work around it by using "[Odbc.Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/odbc-query)".

Comment: The main advantage of Value.NativeQuery is that you can pass parameters without running up against the formula firewall.  Odbc.Query doesn't do that.